# Google Talk - Modify chat messages in real-time

Tags: google-chrome, chat, google-talk

I am trying to develop an application that needs to modify the chat messages on Gtalk in real-time while people are chatting. For example, say I am chatting with X. My application would convert all "Hello" written by X to "Hi" and display them to me (Not required on X's side). How can this be done? Browser extensions or Gtalk chat bots maybe?

Answer (score 0):

If it's worth, I think it should be a similar mechanism to transforming the text (in chat) to emoticons like Gmail does. Using JS or PHP replace methods.

Sorry for my English.